# Can't access shell variable in perl script unless it's an environment variable

Tags: perl

I need to access the value of a shell variable in a perl script.  I can get it if it's an environment variable but not a regular ole shell variable.  Consider

```
% set AAA=Avalue
% setenv BBB=Bvalue
% echo $AAA
Avalue
% echo $BBB
Bvalue
```

So far, so good.  Now, here's a perl script to read them...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

print "AAA: ".$ENV{AAA}."\n";
print "BBB: ".$ENV{BBB}."\n";

exit;
```

When I run it, I get...

```
AAA:
BBB: Bvalue
```

How can I get the value of AAA from inside the perl script ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Oh, forgot to say, default interpreter is c-shell

Comment: I'm not familiar with csh, but my guess would be that `set` only sets environment variables for the current shell, and not for sub-shells. You're obviously setting `BBB` in a different way than you've shown here, or else your example wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I 'setenv BBB".  edited/fixed.  Thanks. (I should have cut/paste)

Comment: Regular ole shell variables are not inherited by their child processes.

Comment: What do you expect from `perl -e'$AAA="Avalue"; $ENV{BBB}="Bvalue"; system("script.pl");`? As you should be realizing now, your request makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting the value of AAA variable because AAA is local env variable where as BBB is exported variable.

Exported variables are carried into the environment of processes started by the shell that exported them, while non-exported variables are local to the current process only.

Example:

```
$ set AAA=123
$ csh
$ echo $AAA
AAA: Undefined variable.
$ exit

$ setenv BBB 456
$ csh
$ echo $BBB
456
```

Comment: So it's a scoping thing.
Fortunately, the perl script is being called by a sourced shell script, so I should be able to set the variables I need as environment variables, then run the perl.
Thanks.

Comment: Re "*So it's a scoping thing*", No, not really. They are different. It's like `my $x;` vs `$ENV{x}` in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

A process doesn't have access to another process's memory, much less its variables. If you want your Perl script to have a value, you will need to pass the value to it somehow (e.g. via its environment).